# Windows 8 store device apps development

Tags: windows-store-apps

We are developing an windows 8 store device app using C# which will communicate to the device using Win32 API and IOCTL calls in a C dll. We had created a C dll with Create File and some IOCTL calls, imported in C# application. Integration goes well and when Create File function is called, it returns 'ACCESS DENIED ERROR'. We had also tried creating Manifest with requested Execution level to Administrator but still the issue is not solved. I would like to know whether Win32 API & IOCTL calls can be used directly or do I need to use any wrapper calls to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried implementing "CreateDeviceAccessInstance"  IDeviceIoControl API for getting the handle and accessing the device but I'm getting E_INVALIDARG for function call to GetResult(). My sequence is as follow 1. ICreateDeviceAccessAsync *pDeviceAccess 2. CreateDeviceAccessInstance (FilePath, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, &pDeviceAccess) - SUCCEEDS 3. pDeviceAccess->Wait(INFINITE) - SUCCEEDS 4. IDeviceIoControl *pDeviceControl 5. pDeviceAccess->GetResult(IID_IDeviceIoControl, (void **)&pDeviceControl) - Fails with E_INVALIDARG error code Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi,

Step 5: Instead of using pDeviceAccess->GetResult(), I had used pDeviceAccess->QueryInterface().  The interface returned is typecasted to DeviceIoControl pointer.  Now I don't get E_INVALIDARG.  But while issuing the IOCTL as per below, I get E_UNEXPECTED error code.

6.  pDeviceControl->DeviceIoControlSync(FSCTL_GET_RETRIEVAL_POINTERS, (UCHAR *) <Pointer to Starting VCN input buffer>, sizeof(STARTING_VCN_INPUT_BUFFER), (UCHAR *) <Pointer to retrieval buffer pointer>, sizeof(retrieval buffer structure), &dwBytesReturned);

Any input would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Not all win32 apis are supported. Please see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br205757.aspx

In particular, CreateFile2() is supported. Have you tried using this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh449422.aspx